# Difficulties in determining efficiency of statistic

Tags: statistics

The following is a sample exam question that I tried to solve with which I had some trouble.

> Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be a sample of independent, identically distributed
>   random variables, with density
>
> $$ f_θ(x) = θx + 1, -\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} $$
>
> for $\theta \in (-2, 2)$. Let $\hat{\theta}_n = 12 \bar{X}$ be an
>   estimator of $\theta$, where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean.
>
> (a) Determine whether  $\hat{\theta}_n$ is unbiased.
>
> (b) Determine whether $\hat{\theta}_n$ is consistent.
>
> (c) Determine whether $\hat{\theta}_n$ is efficient.
>
> (d) Determine the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n
> > - \theta)$.

I solved (a) and (b), and (d) is just computing $\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_n)$ and then using CLT, but (b) is a bit of a problem.

Obviously I'm missing something here, but my thought was to just compute $\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_n)$ and the CRLB (Cràmer-Rao Lower Bound) and then compare them to determine whether the CRLB is attained. I get then

$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_n) = \frac{1}{n}(12 - \theta^2) $$

$$ \text{CRLB} = \frac{1}{n\text{E}((\frac{X_1}{\theta X_1 + 1})^2)} $$

However I'm stuck on calculating this expectation, so something must be wrong then, but I don't seem to see what.

Many thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one given that most of the time Fisher information can be easily rewritten into something recognizable as a variance of something. I would do the integral
$$
E \left[ \left( \frac{X_{1}}{\theta X_{1}+1}\right)^{2}\right] = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \frac{x^{2}}{(\theta x + 1)^{2}} \, (\theta x+1) \,dx
$$
by not canceling the $\theta x + 1$. Instead, make the substitution $u = (\theta x +1)^{2}$ so that $du = 2(\theta x + 1) \, dx$. Then you would have to replace the $x^{2}$ in the numerator with $\frac{1}{\theta^{2}} (\sqrt{u}-1)^{2}$ but things will simplify pretty nicely after that.